# Is it possible to build Apache HtmlEmail from string representation?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, apache-commons

I'm building a [`ImageHtmlEmail`](http://commons.apache.org/email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/ImageHtmlEmail.html) in order to download and embed all the images from given HTML into a multipart email. I need to store that email for sending later.

Problem is, I can get the resulting email text and content-type, but I see no means to construct an `ImageHtmlEmail` back from a text and a content-type. Is it possible at all? Or should I go with raw `javax.mail` for actual sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` out of String representation of an email (ASCII dump as one one get on downloading original email from gmail). However not been very successful in constructing `Email` subclasses like `HtmlEmail` from it yet.

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage  =  MimeMessageUtils.createMimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties()), new ByteArrayInputStream(oneEmail.toString().getBytes()));
```

It does give me most of the things I can think of as useful using its getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "building HtmlEmail from string", but constructing an ImageHtmlMail should be fairly easy, see the sample at http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html, all you need to provide is some html-text via setHtmlMsg()

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail;
...

// load your HTML email template
String htmlEmailTemplate = ....

// define you base URL to resolve relative resource locations
URL url = new URL("http://www.apache.org");

// create the email message
HtmlEmail email = new ImageHtmlEmail();
email.setDataSourceResolver(new DataSourceResolverImpl(url));
email.setHostName("mail.myserver.com");
email.addTo("jdoe@somewhere.org", "John Doe");
email.setFrom("me@apache.org", "Me");
email.setSubject("Test email with inline image");

// set the html message
email.setHtmlMsg(htmlEmailTemplate); 

// set the alternative message
email.setTextMsg("Your email client does not support HTML messages");

// send the email
email.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the basic tutorial, but I need to get farther: I do have a multipart email and can get a textual representation of it. I want to reconstruct the whole `HtmlEmail`, or `MimeMultiPart`, from a String.

Comment: That sounds more like some XML Serialization that extracts the information from the object and provides a text representation which can be put back again, unfortunately I am not very experienced with those...